# List of custom float type in Memoir is misformatted

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am writing a document with `memoir`, and am having a formatting problem with my List of Listings.

I am setting up the Listing type as follows:

```
\newfloat[chapter]{listing}{lol}{Listing}
\newcommand{\listlistingname}{List of Listings}
\newlistof{listoflistings}{lol}{\listlistingname}
```

My `\listoflistings` invocation, however, is producing the following result:

[image]

The built-in lists (`\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`) are working properly. I have also examined the contents of the `.lol` file, and it is indistinguishable form the `lot` and `lof` files.  I do not have `listing`, `lstlistings`, or `listings` loaded.

How might I debug this problem and get my list of listings to behave correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newfloat[chapter]{listing}{lol}{Listing}
\newcommand{\listlistingname}{List of Listings}
\newlistof{listoflistings}{lol}{\listlistingname}
\newlistentry{listing}{lol}{0} % added
% "The other part of creating a new 'List of...', is to specify the formatting of
% the entries" (memoir manual, section 9.3)

\begin{document}

\listoflistings

\chapter{One}

\begin{listing}
Here goes some content.
\caption{\label{lst:one} Listing 1}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}
Here goes some content.
\caption{\label{lst:two} Listing 2}
\end{listing}

\chapter{Two}

\begin{listing}
Here goes some content.
\caption{\label{lst:three} Listing 3}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]